# program modularization (does the if else program below contain the process of modularization?)

Tags: c

hello sorry in advance because i ask a very simple question, but i really ask for help, i have a school assignment, but i don't know how to solve it, please help

Stimulation

After you study program modularization, does the if else program below contain the process of modularization?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int a,b,c, max;
    printf("enter value a :");scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("enter value b :");scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("enter value c :");scanf("%d",&c);
//checking 1 program module
if((a>b)&&(a>c))
{
    max = a;
    printf("highest value checking 1 : %d" ,max);
}else if(b > c)
{
    max=b;
    printf("highest value checking 1 : %d" ,max);
}else{
    max=c;
    printf("highest value checking 1 : %d" ,max);
}

printf("\n");

int number1, number2, number3;
number1=a;
number2=b;
number3=c;

//checking 2 main programs
if((number1>number2)&&(number2>number3)){
 max = number1;
 printf("highest score checking 2 : %d" ,max);
}else if(number2 > number3)
{
 max=number2;
 printf("highest score checking 2 : %d" , max);
}else{
 max=number3;
 printf(highest score checking 2 : %d" ,max);
}

}
```

Identification of problems.

Write down the hypothesis from the results of the if else program study. Is the hypothesis alternative (the if else program line is in accordance with the concept of modularization) or the hypothesis is a null hypothesis (the if else program is not in accordance with the concept of modularization). Explain the hypothesis in detail, and point out which line of if else program strengthens your hypothesis statement!

Comment: Ok, let's first see what is your definition of "modularization".

Comment: In the taxonomy of program architectures, I would not regard an "if-else program" as even a thing.  All but the most trivial of code contains conditional processing.  It is just a _program_.  And for what it is worth, _no_ it exhibits no kind of modularisation whatsoever.  It is a single function in a single source. To be honest, the question makes little sense - especially the part _"point out which line of if else program strengthens your hypothesis_".  I am not even sure the author of the question really understands the meaning of the word _"hypothesis"_ is.

Comment: Moreover "modularisation" is a structure, not a process (unless perhaps it has some domain specific meaning other than that normally applied to programming structure).  Has this question been translated to English, because the question is probably a simple one, but the is horribly obfuscated by the use of somewhat arcane language.

Comment: i'm sorry my english is bad, i'm from vietnam, i'm trying to translate my school assignment and i'm still learning english. I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

The program is *not* modular.

Here is the analysis:

1. The two `if/else` blocks are nearly identical.
2. The `printf` statements are replicated code.
3. The `scanf` calls are replicated code.
4. The code can only handle three numbers.

---

Amongst other things, modularization is a process of eliminating replicated/duplicated code that is similar and placing the common code in [smaller] functions.

A good maxim to follow is that a given function: *should do one thing well*.

We can modularize the code in several steps:

1. Move the first `if/else` block into a separate function (e.g. `getmax`)
2. Eliminate duplicate `printf` in `getmax`
3. Make `getmax` more general so it can handle the second `if/else` more easily
4. Convert second `if/else` block in `main` to use `getmax`
5. Put user input (`printf/scanf`) into common function
6. Convert program to use arrays rather than individual scalars. This is particularly evident with: `int number1,number2,number3;`. It can be simplified into: `int number[3];`
7. Convert program to prompt user for number of elements in the array

---

Move the first `if/else` block into a separate function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// checking 1 program module
int
getmax(int a,int b,int c)
{
    int max;

    if ((a > b) && (a > c)) {
        max = a;
        printf("highest value checking 1 : %d\n", max);
    }
    else if (b > c) {
        max = b;
        printf("highest value checking 1 : %d\n", max);
    }
    else {
        max = c;
        printf("highest value checking 1 : %d\n", max);
    }

    return max;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, max;

    printf("enter value a :");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter value b :");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("enter value c :");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    getmax(a,b,c);

    int number1, number2, number3;

    number1 = a;
    number2 = b;
    number3 = c;

    //checking 2 main programs
    if ((number1 > number2) && (number2 > number3)) {
        max = number1;
        printf("highest score checking 2 : %d\n", max);
    }
    else if (number2 > number3) {
        max = number2;
        printf("highest score checking 2 : %d\n", max);
    }
    else {
        max = number3;
        printf("highest score checking 2 : %d\n", max);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Eliminate duplicate `printf` in `getmax`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// checking 1 program module
int
getmax(int a,int b,int c)
{
    int max;

    if ((a > b) && (a > c)) {
        max = a;
    }
    else if (b > c) {
        max = b;
    }
    else {
        max = c;
    }

    printf("highest value checking 1 : %d\n", max);

    return max;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, max;

    printf("enter value a :");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter value b :");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("enter value c :");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    getmax(a,b,c);

    int number1, number2, number3;

    number1 = a;
    number2 = b;
    number3 = c;

    //checking 2 main programs
    if ((number1 > number2) && (number2 > number3)) {
        max = number1;
        printf("highest score checking 2 : %d\n", max);
    }
    else if (number2 > number3) {
        max = number2;
        printf("highest score checking 2 : %d\n", max);
    }
    else {
        max = number3;
        printf("highest score checking 2 : %d\n", max);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Make `getmax` more general so it can handle the second `if/else` more easily:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// checking 1 program module
int
getmax(const char *what,int a,int b,int c)
{
    int max;

    if ((a > b) && (a > c)) {
        max = a;
    }
    else if (b > c) {
        max = b;
    }
    else {
        max = c;
    }

    printf("highest %s checking 1 : %d\n", what, max);

    return max;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, max;

    printf("enter value a :");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter value b :");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("enter value c :");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    getmax("value",a,b,c);

    int number1, number2, number3;

    number1 = a;
    number2 = b;
    number3 = c;

    //checking 2 main programs
    if ((number1 > number2) && (number2 > number3)) {
        max = number1;
        printf("highest score checking 2 : %d\n", max);
    }
    else if (number2 > number3) {
        max = number2;
        printf("highest score checking 2 : %d\n", max);
    }
    else {
        max = number3;
        printf("highest score checking 2 : %d\n", max);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Convert second `if/else` block in `main` to use `getmax`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// checking 1 program module
int
getmax(const char *what,int a,int b,int c)
{
    int max;

    if ((a > b) && (a > c)) {
        max = a;
    }
    else if (b > c) {
        max = b;
    }
    else {
        max = c;
    }

    printf("highest %s checking 1 : %d\n", what, max);

    return max;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, max;

    printf("enter value a :");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter value b :");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("enter value c :");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    getmax("value",a,b,c);

    int number1, number2, number3;

    number1 = a;
    number2 = b;
    number3 = c;

    //checking 2 main programs
    getmax("score",number1,number2,number3);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Step 6: Put user input into common function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// ask user for number
int
asknum(const char *prompt)
{
    char buf[1000];
    int num;

    printf("enter value %s : ",prompt);
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);

    sscanf(buf,"%d",&num);

    return num;
}

// checking 1 program module
int
getmax(const char *what,int a,int b,int c)
{
    int max;

    if ((a > b) && (a > c)) {
        max = a;
    }
    else if (b > c) {
        max = b;
    }
    else {
        max = c;
    }

    printf("highest %s checking 1 : %d\n", what, max);

    return max;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, max;

    a = asknum("a");
    b = asknum("b");
    c = asknum("c");

    getmax("value",a,b,c);

    int number1, number2, number3;

    number1 = a;
    number2 = b;
    number3 = c;

    //checking 2 main programs
    getmax("score",number1,number2,number3);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Convert program to use arrays rather than individual scalars:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// ask user for number
int
asknum(int prompt)
{
    char buf[1000];
    int num;

    printf("enter value %d : ",prompt);
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);

    sscanf(buf,"%d",&num);

    return num;
}

// checking 1 program module
int
getmax(const char *what,const int *arr,int count)
{
    int idx;
    int val;
    int max = -1;

    if (count > 0) {
        max = arr[0];

        for (idx = 1;  idx < count;  ++idx) {
            val = arr[idx];
            if (val > max)
                max = val;
        }

        printf("highest %s checking 1 : %d\n", what, max);
    }

    return max;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int idx;
    int count = 3;
    int arr[count];

    for (idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        arr[idx] = asknum(idx);

    getmax("value",arr,count);

    int number[count];

    for (idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        number[idx] = arr[idx];

    //checking 2 main programs
    getmax("score",number,count);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Convert program to prompt user for number of elements in the array

```
#include <stdio.h>

// ask user for number
int
asknum(const char *prompt)
{
    char buf[1000];
    int num;

    printf("%s : ",prompt);
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);

    sscanf(buf,"%d",&num);

    return num;
}

// ask user for array value
int
askval(int idx)
{
    char prompt[100];
    int num;

    sprintf(prompt,"Enter array value %d",idx);
    num = asknum(prompt);

    return num;
}

// checking 1 program module
int
getmax(const char *what,const int *arr,int count)
{
    int idx;
    int val;
    int max = -1;

    if (count > 0) {
        max = arr[0];

        for (idx = 1;  idx < count;  ++idx) {
            val = arr[idx];
            if (val > max)
                max = val;
        }

        printf("highest %s value : %d\n", what, max);
    }

    return max;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int idx;

    int count = asknum("Enter the number of array elements");

    int arr[count];
    for (idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        arr[idx] = askval(idx);

    getmax("value",arr,count);

    int number[count];
    for (idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        number[idx] = arr[idx];

    //checking 2 main programs
    getmax("score",number,count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is what i'm looking for, Thank you brother.